# sumar cantidad por año en Mysql

Tags: mysql

vereis tengo dos tablas en mysql. Una llamada `becas` donde tengo (nombre_beca, cuantia, año) y otra `total_becas` (año, total_anual, total_plurianual). En la primera tabla registro sin problemas los datos, pero cuando hago este `INSERT INTO`:

```
INSERT INTO total_becas (año, total_anual, total_plurianual, codigo_persona_total_beca) 
VALUES
(SELECT año FROM becas WHERE año = 2012), 
(SELECT SUM(cuantia) FROM becas WHERE año = 2012 AND codigo_persona_beca = 1), 
(SELECT SUM(cuantia) FROM becas WHERE codigo_persona_beca = 1),
1)
```

El problema lo tengo con el primer select ya que me saca todos los registros que coinciden con ese año y claro Mysql dice que "año" en total_becas no puede tener multiples valores. Lo he intentado solucionar con `GROUP BY año` pero me dice que total_anual y total_plurianual no pueden ser nulos. Entonces no se como puedo solucionarlo. Gracias de antemano

Comment: asi como mandas 1 en codigo de persona, manda 2012 en el primer campo

Comment: los años pueden ser cualquiera no solo 2012 he puesto ese año por poner un ejemplo

Comment: Aca hay una pregunta que solo habla de mysql y solo expresa un problema. Las respuestas dadas son basadas en ese problema. Si tu problema es otro, tus datos vienen de otro lado y no sabes como armar el query, o tus datos estan bien y no sabes pq no muestra, nosotros no lo podemos saber con lo que mostras. Por favor, se claro, mira [ask] y ordena la pregunta, si no la vamos a tener que cerrar porque no es clara

Comment: Vale pues cierra la pregunta porque acabo de ver es otro problema el que tengo, gracias de todos modos

Comment: Alex si queres eliminarla tenes un boton eliminar. Mas alla de eso, tenes 2 respuestas que contestan exactamente lo que preguntaste y de forma correcta. Si ese no era tu problema, no es su culpa...

Comment: de paso, por favor mira el [tour] y fijate como funcionamos

Comment: es que al final he decidido eliminar la tabla total_becas y sacar la cantidad de las becas con un select en vez hacer un insert. Entendido lo del funcionamiento de la pagina, gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Mysql dice que "año" en total_becas no puede tener multiples valores

Aparte de solucion ofrecida por @gbianchi y de tu propia solucion (que es correcta tambien), tengo otra:

```
SELECT año FROM becas WHERE año = 2012 LIMIT 1
```

> pero me dice que total_anual y total_plurianual no pueden ser nulos

Es el error de verdad. Creo que no hay filas en la base de datos con `codigo_persona_beca = 1` y por eso tus dos subconsultas devuelven NULL (`SUM` es NULL cuando no haya filas). Para convertir `NULL` al 0 utiliza `COALESCE`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(cuantia), 0) FROM becas WHERE año = 2012 AND codigo_persona_beca = 1
```

Se explican esta funcion aqui https://parzibyte.me/blog/2018/03/07/mysql-coalescencia-coalesce/

Comment: Ese codigo si que existe, ese campo es un clave ajena que hace referencia a otra tabla que identifica a la persona que recibe la beca. De hecho solo tengo a esa persona cuyo id es 1, yo creo que no suma las cantidades de los años por eso da NULL. Pero probare COALESCE gracias ;)

Answer (score 0):

Ya te lo ha comentado gbianchi, la solución podría pasar por retornar el literal `2012` en tu consulta, pero de todas formas quiero responderte para replantearte tu consulta. Tienes un `insert` con tres subconsultas (dos resolviendo el tema del `año`) las consultas además son casi idéntica salvo alguna cuestión de filtros, por lo que podrías plantear todo como una única consulta haciendo las sumas condicionales:

```
INSERT INTO total_becas (año, total_anual, total_plurianual, codigo_persona_total_beca) 
VALUES
SELECT 2012,
       SUM(CASE WHEN año = 2012 AND codigo_persona_beca = 1 THEN cuantia ELSE NULL END),
       SUM(CASE WHEN codigo_persona_beca = 1 THEN cuantia ELSE NULL END)
       FROM becas
```

Comment: Se me ha olvidado comentaros que los datos los paso por PHP a traves de un formulario. Entonces no solo puede ser 2012 puede ser cualquier año

Comment: Lo que podria hacer, en vez de guardar los totales en una tabla, es sacar esos datos directamente sumados y mostrarlos. Como podria hacer esto??? gracias